# Can't figure out why my code not running for this problem

Tags: scheme, racket

Define a SCHEME function named (implode l) which takes a list of digits in base 10 and
converts them to an integer (the inverse operation of explode). You may only use cons,
car, cdr, functions you wrote in lab or are contained in the lecture slides. You may not use
string or char functions.

```
(define (implode l)
  (define (add-digits l place)
    (if (null? l)
        0
        (+ (* (car l) (expt 10 place))
              (add-digits (cdr l) (+ place l)))))
    (add-digits ((reverse 1)) 0))

(implode (list 1 1))
```

Error im getting

> ```
> mcdr: contract violation
>   expected: mpair?
>   given: 1
> ```

*in R5RS

Comment: Hmmm.... What is `(reverse 1)` supposed to do? Maybe this is a typo, and an illustration of why `l` is a bad name for a variable. You also need to take a closer look at your parentheses; `((reverse l))` is going to cause an error, too.

Comment: You have the same problem with `(+ place l)` --> `(+ place 1)`

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from `(reverse 1)`, which has a typo.
Use a font where you can easily tell the difference between `1` ("one") and `l` ("ell") - you have two such typos.
You also have too many parentheses around the `reverse`.

```
(define (implode l)
  (define (add-digits l place)
    (if (null? l)
        0
        (+ (* (car l) (expt 10 place))
              (add-digits (cdr l) (+ place 1)))))
    (add-digits (reverse l) 0))
```

But you don't need to keep track of the exponent.
Since you have the number "in reverse", you can convert the `cdr`, multiply by ten, and add the `car`.

```
(define (implode l)
  (define (add-digits l)
    (if (null? l)
        0
        (+ (car l) (* 10 (add-digits (cdr l))))))
    (add-digits (reverse l)))
```